# How can I individually change the color of true and false boolean constants in YAML in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml

I'm trying to change the boolean color for "True" in YAML for VS Code. How do I do this?

[image]

I tried asking ChatGPT how, and got this answer to no avail:

```json
{
    ...
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "constant.language.boolean.true.yaml, markup.embedded.block.yaml constant.language.boolean.true",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#0000FF"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: There may be another way to do this, please show an example of your `yaml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the VS Code command palette to see that scopes are available in specific tokens. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme.

As far as I can see from the scope inspector, the default TextMate grammar (see [vscode/yaml/syntaxes/yaml.tmLanguage.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/yaml/syntaxes/yaml.tmLanguage.json)) provides no specific scope for differentiating between true and false boolean constants in YAML.

The best there seems to be is the `constant.language.boolean.yaml` TextMate token scope (which covers both `true` and `false`).

You could write a Pull Request implementing this in the YAML grammar file, or write a feature request issue ticket to the VS Code GitHub repo.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising a PR like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.